# Unexpected output executing a package function

Tags: raku

I have the following dir structure (simplified version to reproduce the issue):

```
testing/
  lib/
   CLI.pm6
  t/
    01-test.t
```

You can check the source [here](https://gist.github.com/antoniogamiz/3a824c2fd8d4727fa6340d2fabc6c05b). The problem is that if you run `raku -Ilib t/01-test.t` you will get the following output:

```
    ok 1 - show help message
    1..1
ok 1 - no arguments provided
    not ok 1 - long version
    # Failed test 'long version'
    # at site#sources\D2E3739A3B53AD1F7CFEE6DA262613FD174A0BC9 (Test::Output) line 84
    # expected a match with: /Documentable\sversion/
    #                   got: "version\r\n"
    1..1
    # You failed 1 test of 1
not ok 2 - version command
# Failed test 'version command'
# at t\01-test.t line 12
1..2
# You failed 1 test of 2
Execute "documentable --help" for more information.
```

Everything seems normal (obviously tests are failing). The problem is the last line:

```
Execute "documentable --help" for more information.
```

That line is added by `CLI::MAIN()`, but is not executed after the tests have finished. You can even comment the first subtest block and it will still appear. This is causing a failed execution of the tests using `prove6 -l`. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `use CLI;` to `use CLI {}`.

## The problem

Presuming the `CLI` package is found, running this:

```
use CLI;
```

will display:

```
Execute "documentable --help" for more information.
```

> Unexpected output

The above is clearly not what you *want*, but your testing code doesn't alter how the `CLI` package is `use`d. So the unwanted message should be *expected* because it is the [`MAIN`](https://docs.raku.org/language/create-cli#index-entry-MAIN) feature working as it is supposed to.<sup>**[1]**</sup>

## A solution

Your question boils down to something like:

> How do I `use` a package with exported `MAIN`s while suppressing the automatic running of those `MAIN`s?

One simple solution is to not import `MAIN` (or rather `&MAIN`<sup>**[2]**</sup>.)

One way to do that is to replace the `use CLI;` with `use CLI {}`.

A `use CLI;` statement is equivalent to `use CLI :DEFAULT;`. (The [`:DEFAULT` tag](https://docs.raku.org/language/modules#Exporting_and_selective_importing) picks up everything that has an `is export` on it without some different tag.)

If you write `use CLI {}` instead then *no* symbols will be imported other than `CLI` itself, which will be bound to the symbols that `CLI` exports *in their package qualified form*.

This way your *manual* tests of `MAIN` (which specify the *package* -- `CLI::MAIN`) will continue to work, but *automatic* invocation of it will be suppressed.

## Footnotes

<sup>**[1]**</sup> In case the doc doesn't make things clear:

- The `is export` on the `our proto MAIN` declaration in the `CLI` package *exports* a `&MAIN`<sup>**[2]**</sup> [symbol](https://docs.raku.org/language/glossary#index-entry-Symbol);
- The `use` statement *imports* that `&MAIN` symbol into `t/01-test.t`'s lexical scope;
- The command `raku ... t/01-test.t` invokes `t/01-test.t` without arguments, as does `prove6 -l ...` (assuming no additional arguments beyond the lib are passed to the mainline). So a zero argument `&MAIN` call is invoked;
- The zero argument call resolves to the zero parameter `multi MAIN() { note 'Execute ... information'; }` declaration. So you see its message.

<sup>**[2]**</sup> A sub declaration like `MAIN` declares a symbol `&MAIN`. (And a sub *call* like `MAIN blah blah` calls the routine associated with `&MAIN`.)

Comment: But how can I fix it? If I delete `is export` from `RUN-MAIN` it still appears and if I delete it from `proto MAIN` then any command will be executed.

Comment: Oh, I can delete de `RUN-MAIN` hack and commands still work. Though even deleting `RUN-MAIN` sub the message still appears.

Comment: I think I've finally got my answer about right. PLMK if the new version is helpful or confusing. Thanks.

Comment: THANKS for the helpful answer, now I understand a lot more about what's going on :).